# Spring Boot cant renderize jsp file and wants to download it on browser

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I've lost lots of time reading articles about my problem but i cant find a solution.

As the title says: i cant see the rendered jsp in my browser. My browser is trying to downlad the jsp file instead.

**Files Structure**

```
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── blablabla
│   │   │                   └── server
│   │   │                       ├── Application.java
│   │   │                       ├── Controller.java
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   └── application.properties
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       └── WEB-INF
│   │           └── status.jsp
```

**My pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
```

**My Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**My Controller**

```
@Controller
public class CallCenterController {

    private Integer maxCalls;

    private Dispatcher dispatcher;

    @Autowired
    public CallCenterController(Integer maxCalls, Dispatcher dispatcher) {
        this.maxCalls = maxCalls;
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/status")
    public ModelAndView status(Map<String, Object> model) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("status");
        modelAndView.addObject("maxCalls", maxCalls);
        modelAndView.addObject("connectedAgents", dispatcher.getAvailableAgents());
        modelAndView.addObject("dispatchedCustomers", dispatcher.countDispatchedCustomers());
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

I know there is a lot of questions with the same problem, but i think I'm missing something.
Thanks for helping.

**ADDED after asking**

I just added a resolver on the same package than controller an Application but nothing changes.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        //resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        //resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add a JSP view resolver?

Comment: I Just added a View Resolver but nothing happens